# Access denied when trying to move a file via command line

Tags: command-line, windows-server-2003

**Edited**

I need to move a subfolder to another subfolder.  When I use this command:

`move e:\rootfolder\sourcefolder c:\rootfolder\destfolder`

I get `Access is denied`.

Notice how the source drive is e: and the destination is c:.  I believe the first answerer was right about this being the problem with the cmd.exe.  I will give it some time before I mark their answer.

Comment: When I try this on Windows 7, creating both a source and destination folder as per your command, it "just works".  Have you checked ownership and permissions on the destfolder?

Comment: I can move the folder via click and drag using Explorer, so I'd have to assume that my permissions are adequate.

Comment: You can sometimes get permission error if the source folder is in use, including if the folder is opened by a command prompt or by explorer.

Comment: I assume permissions based. Please note, scripts are not guaranteed to run with the same permissions as the account you're logged in on.

Comment: Dave Rook - Yes, a subfolder, in fact.  I tried moving them to a subfolder of C:, but I am getting the same error.

Comment: I got it to work.  Apparently, it is some sort of weird permissions thing that applies only to the C drive and command prompt.  I was trying to copy subfolders from E: to subfolders in C:.  Changing the destination to E: worked, but I'd still like to know why since I was able to drag files from E to C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is the expected behavior (for some odd reason) when trying to move folders between drives.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849852.aspx

> Move-Item will move files between drives that are supported by the same provider, but it will move directories only within the same drive.

I know that link says it applies to Windows Powershell, but I just tested on my XP machine here at work and see the exact same behavior, so I believe it applies to cmd.exe as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's a circuitous method to say the least, but as I encounter this frequently, I came up with a solution that accomplishes the same thing with no major speed difference.  Requires that you have `7z.exe` (can be downloaded  [here](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html)) installed, and added to your path. 7z is a fast command line archiver, thus this could also be done with `tar.exe`,`gzip.exe`, etc.

I do something like the following:

```
7z a x:\destinationfolder\tmp.7z c:\directoryyouwanttomove && ^
7z x x:\destinationfolder\tmp.7z
```

I recognize that this is way old, and I'm not specifically answering the op's question, but I had a really hard time finding this documented anywhere, and I perhaps could save someone some pain.